# catch block not working in c++ native library

Tags: java, c++, exception, java-native-interface, native

I am writing a java native library in c++, and using exception handling within native lib itself, but the library crashes as soon as I throw exception. Here is my simple test program, when I call it from Java test, it just crashes as soon as exception is thrown. The catch block is not working. Any ideas what i am missing. Thanks.

```
#include "Test.h"
#include <iostream>

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_helloWorld(JNIEnv *, jobject)
{
    std::cout<<"Hello World";
    try {
        throw 1;
    }
    catch(int )
    {
        std::cout<<" catch int block"<<std::endl;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        std::cout<<" catch block"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

Compile and Link:

```
g++ -m64 -fPIC -fexceptions -c test.cpp
g++ -shared -m64 -Wl,-soname,libtest.so -Wl,-shared-libgcc test.o -o libtest.so

$ java  -d64 -Djava.library.path=/home/vkumar/projects/test -cp $CLASSPATH Test
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
terminate called recursively
Hello World^CAbort (core dumped)
```

Comment: what platform? what vendor and version of java?

Comment: SunOS 5.10, GCC 4.3.3 and JDK 1.6.0, I tried compiling all in 32 bit mode, but same results.

Comment: I remember having had a similar problem some years ago on Solaris. Back then, the problem was using GCC, the GNU linker and shared libraries. We solved the problem by using the Sun linker and by linking to static binaries. Obviously, the try/catch implementation of GCC needed linker support that was not compatible with the Sun dynamic linker. You could try to use a different linker, since going static won't help in a Java environment.

Comment: Thanks Tobias, luckily I have one more GCC build which uses solaris linker. I am going to try it and see how it goes.

Comment: I tried it with solaris linker, but same results.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your examplea and everything went fine. My environment is Ubuntu 12.04 (64bit) with Oracle JDK 1.7.

So, my guess is your environment is the culprit. Since you use option `-m64`, it could be a mismatch between 32 bit system and 64 bit libtest.so.

Please verify your system, JDK, gcc, etc. fits all together.

Comment: Thanks, I will check the compatibility between all components involved. I m using Solaris 5.10, gcc 4.3.3 and jdk 1.6

Comment: @vkumar I retried with OpenJDK 6 and OpenJDK 7 (gcc 4.6.3). Same result: success.

Comment: Thanks Olaf, I am going to try with different version of GCC. Our target prod env. is Sun Solaris, I would not be able to change that. But if its compiler issue, I can always upgrade it. Thanks again.

Comment: Olaf - you are right. I built the 32 bit libtest.so and it works fine in 32 bit mode. Does it mean i would need to install 64 bit java?, I was in impression that java with -d64 mode make sure that the server runs in 64 bit mode?

Comment: @vkumar I'm not familiar with SunOS, but I guess so. In Ubuntu I have appropriate packages for 64 bit (amd64) and 32 bit (i386), depending on system/hardware environment. I also downloaded the "x64-linux" JDK package from Oracle. So, this should be the same for your environment.

Comment: @vkumar I just googled a bit about Solaris and it might be, that `uname -a` tells you wether you're running 32 bit or 64 bit kernel.

Comment: vkumar@rv-dv-ixte-03 $ uname -a
SunOS 5.10 Generic_142901-14 i86pc i386 i86pc Solaris
vkumar@rv-dv-ixte-03 $

Comment: @vkumar This seems to be 32 bit (i386). It explains, why the code works in 32 bit mode and not when compiled for 64 bit environment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like exception was uncaught. Try

```
int i=1;

try {
    throw i;
}
```

may be a problem with `int` size or something? Or you forgot to recompile?

Comment: No, i made sure that i deleted .so, .o and recompiled everything. even if there is issue with int size the catch(...) should catch it.

Answer (score 0):

Is JNIExport or JNICALL expanding to define c linkage ?  if so then you're throwing a C++ exception in a c function and I'm not sure that behaviour is defined.

maybe try something like

```
namespace 
{
  void impl() 
  {   
     ... yourCode ...
  } 
}

JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_Test_helloWorld(JNIEnv *, jobject)
{
   impl();
}
```

Comment: It is not a problem to throw and catch an exception in an extern "C" function. It would be a problem to let the exception escape said function.